# Puppet agent not using modulepath setting

Tags: configuration, puppet, agent

I have installed Puppet Agent 3.7 on an AWS Ubuntu machine.

After receiving a 'could not find class' error, I added a **modulepath** entry to the **/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf** file.

**modulepath=/home/ubuntu/repos/puppet-tests/modules**

However, if I run the following command, I am told that the module path(s) haven't changed.

```
puppet apply --configprint modulepath
```

i.e.

**/home/ubuntu/.puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules**

I have tried placing the **modulepath** setting in both the **[main]** and **[agent]** sections.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puppet `confdir` depends on user that executes puppet command. That's why puppet cofiguration will differ for different users.  Please read the documentation about [confdir location](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/dirs_confdir.html#location), and check the following example:

```
vagrant@mytest:~$ puppet apply --configprint modulepath
/home/vagrant/.puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules

vagrant@mytest:~$ sudo su 
root@mytest:/home/vagrant# puppet apply --configprint modulepath
/etc/puppet/modules/lib:/etc/puppet/modules:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules
```

Summarizing, execute puppet as a root, or modify puppet config for non root user in `~/.puppet` directory.

Comment: Thanks kkamilpl. Off to try that now.

Comment: kkamilpl. Thanks again for your answer. I have had chance to experiment and it was exactly as you said. I had edited the /etc/puppet/puppet.conf file which is used if puppet agent is run as root but if running as current user (ubuntu on an AWS machine) then it is looking in ~/.puppet/puppet.conf which doesn't exist and so I am getting the default path. Perfect. Thanks again.